# I somehow glitched into New Donk City`s Tallest building

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

I somehow glitched into New Donk City`s tallest building, so I closed Mario odyssey. I then went back in, but I’m still in the building and I can’t get out! Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you actually close it, or did you just go to the home screen?

Answer (score 6):

Is Mario on solid ground?

If so, you can open the map with `-` and select a checkpoint to return to.